# Polymer: Dots at the ends aren't in the middle

Tags: vertical-alignment, chemfig

So currently it's looking like this:

[image: How it looks like]

Here's the minimal code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
        \begin{align*}
            \schemestart
                \chemname{
                    \chemfig{
                        \ldots
                        -[0]C
                            ( -[2]H)
                            ( -[-2]H)
                        % First C-atom with COOH
                        -C
                            ( -[2]{CH3})
                            (-[6]C
                                ( =[7]\charge{360=\|, 270=\|}{O})
                                ( -[5]\charge{315=\|, 135=\|}{O}
                                     ( -[6]H)
                                )
                            )
                        -[0]C
                            ( -[2]H)
                            ( -[-2]H)
                        % Second C-atom with COOH
                        -C
                            ( -[2]{CH3})
                            (-[6]C
                                ( =[7]\charge{360=\|, 270=\|}{O})
                                ( -[5]\charge{315=\|, 135=\|}{O}
                                     ( -[6]H)
                                )
                            )
                        -[0]C
                            ( -[2]H)
                            ( -[-2]H)
                        % Third C-atom with COOH
                        -C
                            ( -[2]{CH3})
                            (-[6]C
                                ( =[7]\charge{360=\|, 270=\|}{O})
                                ( -[5]\charge{315=\|, 135=\|}{O}
                                     ( -[6]H)
                                )
                            )
                        -[0]\ldots
                    }
                }
                {Polymer}
            \schemestop
        \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

As you can see the dots on the right are a little bit lower than the electron-connection on the left, next to it. Do you have an idea how I can fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a solution with a trick

```
\chemfig{
                        \ldots
                        -[0]C
                            ( -[2]H)
                            ( -[-2]H)
                        % First C-atom with COOH
                        -C
                            ( -[2]{CH3})
                            (-[6]C
                                ( =[7]\charge{360=\|, 270=\|}{O})
                                ( -[5]\charge{315=\|, 135=\|}{O}
                                     ( -[6]H)
                                )
                            )
                        -[0]C
                            ( -[2]H)
                            ( -[-2]H)
                        % Second C-atom with COOH
                        -C
                            ( -[2]{CH3})
                            (-[6]C
                                ( =[7]\charge{360=\|, 270=\|}{O})
                                ( -[5]\charge{315=\|, 135=\|}{O}
                                     ( -[6]H)
                                )
                            )
                        -[0]C
                            ( -[2]H)
                            ( -[-2]H)
                        % Third C-atom with COOH
                        -C
                            ( -[2]{CH3})
                            (-[6]C
                                ( =[7]\charge{360=\|, 270=\|}{O})
                                ( -[5]\charge{315=\|, 135=\|}{O}
                                     ( -[6]H)
                                )
                            )
                        -\Charge{180=$\,\ldots$}{\vphantom{C}}
                    }
```

[image]

Comment: Dayum. Learned two new things: 1. That what you have posted 2. There **is** a difference between `\charge` and `\Charge` Thank you very much! c(^-^)c